# Creating object in method call parameters returns empty object?

Tags: c++

Assuming i have this header file containing the Model class

```
class Model
{
public:
    vector<Texture> textures_loaded;
    vector<Mesh>    meshes;
    string directory;

    Model() {}

    Model(string const& path)
    {
        /* Code */
    }
}
```

and Entity class:

```
class Entity
{
public:
    
    Entity(Model* model, glm::mat4 matrix) {
        this->entityModel = model;
        this->modelMatrix = matrix;
    }

    void Draw(Shader& shader) {
        /* Code */
    }

    Model* entityModel;
    glm::mat4 modelMatrix;


};
```

and entities vector is as follows.

```
vector<Entity> entities;
```

Are the following 2 snippets of code not identical in C++?

```
Model modelPlayer = Model("some param");
entities.push_back(Entity(&modelPlayer, player1_matrix));
```

```
entities.push_back(Entity(&Model("some param"), player1_matrix));
```

When using the debugger using the second snippet of code, all the fields within Model are uninitialized/empty (meshes for example)? Its almost like if it's getting garbage collected, but I can't formulate the question properly to find answers online.

Comment: Where did you define `Entity`?

Comment: You're going to have serious lifetime issues if you give an address of a temporary. You should also get compiler warnings. This is why pointers are a bad plan. You could fix this with `std::shared_ptr` but it just makes a mess of things if you can instead just `emplace_back` your Model.

Comment: @tadman I think it could work if the constructor handles the problem. A pointer us passed to the constructor of `Entity`. The constructor can dereference it and copy the object.

Comment: @ThomasSablik How could it? By cloning that object by pointer? It's a sign of a wonky design at least, but more likely a huge problem.

Comment: Without [mcve] we can't say if this is a bug or "uncommon" design.

Comment: @WaisKamal i added the Entity class so you can see.

Comment: Ok, now we see it. It's a bug and tadman's assumption was correct. You are storing a pointer to a temporary object. It's destroyed instantly after the constructor call. Dereferencing it causes undefined behavior.

Comment: There is no garbage collection in C++.

You are taking an address of temporary object through non-const pointer. `Model` will seize to exists immediately after the end of the `push_back` statement.

Comment: But since i have the pointer to the new Entity object, it isn't a leak right? I store the pointer for later use? I think i might have a fundamental misunderstanding about this. I try avoid to pass object by value since they can be very large (vector with millions of values).

Comment: But the object is destroyed. Your pointer points to nowhere. The object only exists in that line and only in that line the pointer points to a valid object.

Comment: So C++ does do garbage collection then?
What do you mean by destroyed, if it's created its in memory, i got the pointer to that memory address, so something is clearing that memory, so it's garbage collected??

Comment: The object has [automatic storage duration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration). That's very different to garbage collection. Every automatic object has a scope and is destroyed when it leaves its scope. You know exactly when an object is destroyed.

Comment: The big question here is: who *owns* the object... a pointer is just a memory address locating an object, but something must own it. I.e. also clean it up after you're done. What is it in your case? It could be that you shouldn't use pointers here in the first place...

Comment: Other thing, if the object is very large, it could still be low cost to transfer ownership if you `std::move` it. But the move constructor or assignment has to be properly implemented for the class (it is for std::vector).

Comment: A simple solution could be: Create a list of models (not pointers). Pass a pointer of the model to the entity. Don't destroy the list or the node while the program is running.

Answer (score 2):

The key thing to learn in C++ is [scope](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope). When that variable *falls out of scope* it is destroyed and effectively becomes a ghost. You may be able to use its ghostly form for a short period of time but it's *undefined behaviour* because that memory can be overwritten without notice.

The bug is you're using the address of a temporary, it is out of scope almost instantly. You need to persist that for longer. One solution is [`std::shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) which is a reference-counted "garbage collection" mechanism of sorts:

```cpp
std::shared_ptr<Model> modelPlayer = std::make_shared<Model>(Model("some param"));
entities.push_back(Entity(modelPlayer, player1_matrix));
```

A shared pointer overrides `*` and `->` operators so it behaves as transparently like the original pointer as it possibly can when used.

Where it's important to match that type on the receiving end, of course:

```cpp
class Entity
{
public:
    Entity(std::shared_ptr<Model> model, glm::mat4 matrix) : entityModel(model), modelMatrix(matrix) {
    }

    std::shared_ptr<Model> entityModel;
}
```

Note the use of a [constructor list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor) here. Additionally, the `this->` part is something you'll only use where you have [variable shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) issues, it's normally not necessary nor recommended.

When the last reference to that pointer falls out of scope, that object is automatically cleaned up. In other words, the lifetime of this particular Model is as long as the last Entity to make use of it.

Comment: `std::shared_ptr<Model*> ` ... a shared pointer to a pointer/ heap allocated object?

Comment: Thanks for that, but i am still really confused, i am getting compiler errors now saying no suitable conversion from std::shared_ptr<Model*> to Model *.
Also "No instance of std::make_shared matches argument list"

Comment: I had to convert the property too, so that's updated.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to create the model in the Entity constructor and store the object instead of a shared pointer? You could completely remove the shared pointer part.

Comment: @ThomasSablik The original code isn't very suitable for testing, so I've had to do something from scratch. Updating. I'm presuming the models are shared among different entities, hence the need for a shared pointer. This is how instancing generally works in game engines.

Comment: Models need to be reused between many entites (Shared). So i need to create them first, then create the entities using the shared model.

Comment: @tadman How can I use what's stored in the Shared_pointer? I'm reading the link you posted, but I'm just getting useless compilation errors. "Expression must have pointer to class type".
Sorry about this I am completely clueless of this shared_pointer.

Comment: And std::make_shared still throwing an error "No instance of function template std::make_shared matches argument list. Argument types are Model *"

Comment: @FrancescoGorini Of course you can share pointers to that objects. Create an object and store it. Create pointers to that object and share them. There should be one owner and there can be many users. At least I would use `std::unique_ptr` instead of `std:: shared_ptr` if possible.

Comment: @ThomasSablik Is there a better approach to use here? If these are actually shared between N Entity objects, was thinking `std::shared_ptr` was the way to go.

Comment: @tadman It's difficult to say without more details. I don't see the necessity for shared pointers because in the question OP creates one temporary model object for one entity. Nothing is shared there. A model manager could solve the problem of shared models.

Comment: @ThomasSablik Yes sorry that's a bad example.
I would make a Model object, and then hundreds if not thousands of Entity objects using that 1 Model, i just didn't include it in the example.

My issue was solved by using "new" in the example code above, i understand this isn't ideal, but i still don't fully understand C++ objects. I can't get the compiler to accept using shared_pointers for now.

Comment: @FrancescoGorini Are you using delete, too or are you leaking memory?

Comment: Yeah i understand it's good to avoid "new" in C++. 
At the moment i am creating new object and storing them in a * vector.
Later on I call delete on each one in a loop.

Comment: A `std::vector` will call the destructor automatically if you don't use pointers. If you *need* to use pointers, consider a wrapper like [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) to help release it for you automatically.